# Subject of the embeded clause

Tags: sentence-structure

I have difficulty to understand the syntax of this undermentioned sentence:

> 1. Sie sagt, dass man Schönheit nur schwer definieren kann.

In English, Polish and Lithuanian we would say:

> *She says that beauty can be difficult to define.*

My question is:

Can we also say (would Native German speaker actually use such sentence):

> 2. Sie sagt, dass Schonheit schwer zu definieren ist.

If yes: what is the difference?
If not: why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your difficulty about the **man**? *Man* is a fill-in-noun meaning *someone* or simply *one*.

> Sie sagt, dass **man** Schönheit nur schwer definieren kann.

*She says **one** can define beauty rather hard.*

So *man* is the subject in the dependent clause, and *Schönheit* is an accusative object.

---

The other example you gave is also valid German but it means a slightly different thing.

> Sie sagt, dass Schönheit schwer zu definieren ist.

*She says beauty is hard to define.*

That's *Zustandspassiv*. *Die Schönheit* has a property *schwer zu definieren*.

The third way to say something like that is

> Sie sagt, dass Schönheit schwer definiert werden kann.

*She says beauty is hard to be defined.*

That's *Vorgangspassiv*. Anyone has a hard time to define beauty.

Comment: Good, answer, but there is no difference in meaning between the OPs two proposed German sentences.

Comment: I doubt that "Schönheit ist schwer zu definieren" is Zustandspassiv. Zustandspassiv would be "Schönheit ist schwer definiert" (Grammatically valid but unusual and somewhat ambiguous).